# nestjs not recognizing middleware written for particular method in a controller

Tags: typescript, routes, controller, nestjs, middleware

My controller looks like this

@Controller('***jobtitles***')

export class JobtitlesController {

@Patch(':id')

update(

```
@Param('id') id: string,

@Body() updateJobtitleDto: UpdateJobtitleDto,
```

) {

```
 return this.jobtitlesService.update(+id, updateJobtitleDto);
```

}

}

My app.module.ts tries to inject a middleware on above controllers PATCH method only.

Here is how my code looks like in app.module.ts

*

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(JobtitleMiddleware)
      .forRoutes({ path: 'jobtitles', method: RequestMethod.PATCH });
  }
}
```

- 

But it never calls my middleware dont know why.

My middleware code is very simple

*

```
export class JobtitleMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    console.log('Request...');
    next();
  }
}
```

- 

Answer (score 0):

The root cause was in my request method i.e. PATCH(':id') I am expecting a paramter for ID so, in order to map with this I need to modify my path as 'jobtitles/:id' while applying middlware path.

i.e.

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(JobtitleMiddleware)
      .forRoutes({ path: 'jobtitles/:id', method: RequestMethod.PATCH });
  }
}
```

Hope this will be helpfull to someone.